# Stucking in the pointer swap loop in c

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I'm trying to learn C right now and there is an example which doesn't let me use `string.h` or other functions.

For example, I need to reverse string with pointers.

But when I swap, it's stuck.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void reverseCopy( char *, char *, int);

int main(){
    char *word1 = "Welcome to the C programming";
    char word2[50];
    int i,count;

    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
        if(word1[i]=='\0') break;
        count++;
    }

    reverseCopy(word1,word2,count);

    return 0;
}

void reverseCopy( char * g1, char * g2 ,int lenght){
    g2=g1;
    char temp;
    int i;
    int j=temp-1;

    for(i=0;i<j/2;i++){
        temp=*(g2+i);
        *(g2+i)=*(g2+j-i);
        *(g2+j-i)=temp;
    }

    puts(g2);
}
```

Comment: Think a little bit about what the assignment `g2=g1` does. Also think about why it's recommended to use `const char *` to point to string literals (your text book should have that information).

Comment: I solved your problem you can check the answer

Comment: @MohamedKaram,  It is very likely that Bahadir is a student and this is an assignment that they are expected to solve by their self.  Therefore, it is best to point to problems and (possibly) suggest fixes.  It is not helping Bahadir to give them a complete, working answer

Answer (score 1):

Such a string function that copies a string in the reverse order to a character array should have only two parameters: the destination character array and the source string. It is assumed that the destination character array is large enough to accommodate the source string.

As for your function `reverseCopy` definition then even the first statement of the function

```
g2=g1;
```

makes the function senseless because after this statement the address of the destination character array is lost.

This assignment does not copies the string pointed to by `g1` in the character array pointed to by `g2` as you evidently think. This assignment makes the pointers `g1` and `g2` to point to the same string that is to the string literal passed to the function as an argument.

Now after this assignment you are trying to reverse the string literal that results in undefined behavior.

Moreover you are using uninitialized variables like

```
char temp;
//...
int j=temp-1;
```

If the function should be written using only pointers then you should not use an integer variable `i`  that plays the role of an index.

And the function should not output anything. It is the caller of the function that will decide whether to output anything if any.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented using only pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * reverseCopy( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    const char *last = s2;

    while ( *last ) ++ last;

    char *first = s1;

    while ( last != s2 )
    {
        *first++ = *--last;
    }

    *first = '\0';

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s1 = "Welcome to the C programming";
    char s2[50];

    puts( s1 );
    puts( reverseCopy( s2, s1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Welcome to the C programming
gnimmargorp C eht ot emocleW
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the problem bcs of `int j = temp-1` while temp is a char , also the assignement of `g2=g1` was causing you a problem

i can suggest you the following one :

```
void reverseCopy( char * g1, char * g2 ,int lenght){
int i;
for(i=0;i<=lenght;i++){
    g2[i]=*(g1+lenght-i);
}
puts(g2);
}
}
```

**Main :**

```
int main(){
char *word1 = "Welcome to the C programming";
char word2[50];
int i,count;
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    if(word1[i]=='\0') break;
    count++;
}

reverseCopy(word1,word2,count);

return 0;
```

}

**Output :**

```
gnimmargorp C eht ot emocleW
```

Answer (score 0):

the posted code, when run through the compiler, results in:

```
gcc   -O1  -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -c "untitled2.c"  -I. (in directory: /home/richard/Documents/forum)

untitled2.c: In function ‘reverseCopy’:

untitled2.c:15:45: warning: unused parameter ‘lenght’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 void reverseCopy( char * g1, char * g2 ,int lenght){
                                         ^~~~~~

untitled2.c:19:15: warning: ‘temp’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
 int j=temp-1;
       ~~~~^~

untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled2.c:9:14: warning: ‘count’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     count++;
     ~~~~~^~

Compilation finished successfully.
```

Accessing/using variables that are not initialized is undefined behavior.

This statement:

```
Compilation finished successfully.
```

just means the compiler produced some 'workaround' for the problems.  It does NOT mean that the resulting code performs what you are expecting it to.

When compiling, enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The above output from the compiler shows the options I use for `gcc`.  Other compilers use different options to produce the same results

the posted code is not ready for linking.

Fix the problems, then get back to us.

OT: for ease of readability and understanding:

1. use an appropriate space:  inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.
2. separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line
3. separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)